# Как правильно написать запрос?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlalchemy

у меня есть таблица Order.

```
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    status = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    created_at = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime(), server_default=sqlalchemy.sql.func.now(), nullable=False)
    updated_at = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime(), server_default=sqlalchemy.sql.func.now(), onupdate=sqlalchemy.sql.func.now())
    cluster_uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(UUID(as_uuid=False))
    params = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy_jsonfield.JSONField(enforce_string=False, enforce_unicode=False), default="{}")
    request_logs = relationship(RequestLog)
    snapshots = relationship(Snapshot)
```

и штука для запросов

```
db = SessionLocal()
```

Запрос работает:
`db.query(Order).filter(text("CAST(params->>'parent_order_id' AS INTEGER) = :id")).params(id = id).all()`

А этот не работает
`db.query(Order).filter(text("type = :v")).params(v='vdc').all()`

1. Что я делаю не так?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1802, in _execute_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> line 719, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is
> aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
> line 2759, in all
> return self._iter().all()   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
> line 2894, in _iter
> result = self.session.execute(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 1689, in execute
> result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)   File
> "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1614, in _execute_20
> return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)   File
> "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
> line 325, in _execute_on_connection
> return connection._execute_clauseelement(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1481, in _execute_clauseelement
> ret = self._execute_context(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1845, in _execute_context
> self.*handle_dbapi_exception(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 2026, in *handle_dbapi_exception
> util.raise*(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
> line 207, in raise*
> raise exception   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1802, in _execute_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "/home/fuckingforest/orchestrator_py/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> line 719, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction)
> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
> transaction block
>
> [SQL: SELECT orders.id AS orders_id, orders.uuid AS orders_uuid,
> orders.type AS orders_type, orders.status AS orders_status,
> orders.created_at AS orders_created_at, orders.updated_at AS
> orders_updated_at, orders.cluster_uuid AS orders_cluster_uuid,
> orders.params AS orders_params  FROM orders  WHERE
> CAST(params->>'parent_order_id' AS INTEGER) = %(id)s and type = %(v)s]
> [parameters: {'id': 4, 'v': 'vdc'}] (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/2j85)

2. Как писать запрос с 2мя условиями, но одним запросом? Что то типо `db.query(Order).filter(text("CAST(params->>'parent_order_id' AS INTEGER) = :id and type = :v")).params(id = 4, v='vdc').all()`
   Просто дальше планируется внутри text() подставлять строку, которая будет формироваться динамически.
3. Запрос вида
   `db.query(Order).filter(условие1).filter(условие2).all()` это же по сути 2 запроса и лучше (быстрее) писать `db.query(Order).filter(условие1 and условие2).all()` ?

Comment: Дайте трейсбэк ошибки.

Comment: Добавлено в описание вопроса